# Obtaining pixels between 2 raster layers (border)?

Tags: raster, r, distance, pixel

I have a rasterStack obtained from a stack of 3 raster layers by:

```
    image = stack(A, B, C)
```

I would like to calculate the distance between the pixels of layer A and pixels of layer C. After obtaining SpatialPoints of these 2 layers I used:

```
    A_pts = as(red,"SpatialPoints")[red[]==1]
    C_pts = as(blue,"SpatialPoints")[blue[]==1]
    Distance_AC <- gDistance(A_pts, C_pts, byid=TRUE)
```

But as the number of pixels are huge the calculating process cannot finish.

Therefore I would like to calulate the distance between the layer C and only the pixels of the layer A that are in contact with layer C = the distance between pixels of layer A and the pixels of the border between A/C.

How could get these pixels between layer A and C as illustrated in the  following image ?

[image]

Comment: If the size of your problem is a problem you should state what that size is in your question. As I understand it you want the distance from each red pixel to the *nearest* blue pixel? Write some functions to create sample data at various sizes and that will make it easier for us to work on it. Have you looked at specialised nearest-neighbour packages like FNN?

Comment: FNN can compute the nearest neighbour of a million points from another million points in 6 seconds on my laptop.

Comment: Or do you really want the NxM distances between all the red pixels and all the border pixels, for N red pixels and M border pixels? Use an edge-detection filter to get the edge pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do your layers A and C just have `NA` where they don't have a value?

i'd suggest using `raster::distance`. Just run separately for rasters A and C and `merge` (if relevant)

Here's a dummy for you, ncells = 1 million, using an extremely crude boundary line;

```
require(raster)

# make 2 rasters (your A and C), with generic values
r1 <- raster(xmn=0, xmx=1000, ymn=0, ymx=1000, ncol=1000, nrow=1000)
r2 <- raster(xmn=0, xmx=1000, ymn=0, ymx=1000, ncol=1000, nrow=1000)

r1[] <- 1
r2[] <- 2

# make a boundary polygon (crude here)

x_coord <- c(300,350,500, 500, 600, 700, 600, 800, 800, 900, 1000,1000)
y_coord <- c(0,200,400, 400, 500, 550, 450, 500, 600, 650, 700,0)
xym <- cbind(x_coord, y_coord)
p = Polygon(xym)
ps = Polygons(list(p),1)
sps = SpatialPolygons(list(ps))

# mask the two rasters with the boundary polygon just to make the data look like yours
r1.m <- mask(r1, sps, inverse = T)
r2.m <- mask(r2, sps)

# in this plot the rasters have been merged for visual aid, you don't need to
```

[image]

```
# use raster::distance to establish distance between NA and nearest cell of value. 
# My data was masked by the polygon but yours should already contain the NA data
# output is another raster

dists.to.r1 <- distance(r1.m)
dists.to.r2 <- distance(r2.m)

# you now have 2 rasters; distance of NA in r1 to nearest data in r1, and same for r2

# ADD them together (0 in one layer will be > 0 in other)
# this is, in effect, the distance of one raster to the other raster (i.e. nearest NA)

all.dists <- dists.r1 + dists.r2
plot(all.dists)
```

[image]

the distance code take a few seconds with this dummy data